# Удаление класса внутри родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую простенький скрипт для переключения активных элементов. Но, столкнулся с проблемой. Для начал код:

```js
$(".ml .label").click(function() {
  $(".ml .label").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ml">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td><label class="label">Текст 1</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td><label class="label">Текст 2</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td><label class="label">Текст 3</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="ml">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td><label class="label">Текст 1</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td><label class="label">Текст 2</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td><label class="label">Текст 3</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Я понимаю, что проходит по обеим таблицам и удаляет все активные классы. Но, как сделать так, чтоб удаление класса было только в родительском блоке? Пробовал через .parent(), но конструкция не работает. Как я понимаю, из-за того, что указанный класс не является родителем для `.label`. Заранее благодарен за подсказку.

PS: Не спрашивайте почему тут таблица)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
$(this).closest(".ml").find(".label").removeClass("active");
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно!